# OLD error minecraft server 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I created a server downloaded from minecraft.net. And i have a brother, and we played a lot of worlds together. But, a day, when we play in the server with a world created in the 1.5, the server says "OLD"
How i can fix this error? I REALLY WANT TO PLAY IN THAT WORLD AND I CANT!
PLS help me.

Comment: You'll have to update your server: http://m.wikihow.com/Update-a-Minecraft-Server

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to use the 1.5 version when playing on that world. Sorry for any inconveniences.